# Получение select'a из хранимой процедуры в контроллер и вывод в представление

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getviews] @n int =1, @psize int=20 as select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by RecorderId) as id,* from AllSensors ) as t1 where id BETWEEN @n*@psize-(@psize-1) AND @n*@psize
```

Имеется данная хранимая процедура. С ее помощью необходимо получить выборку в контроллере (aspnet) и передать его в представление.

```
var sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("getviews", sqlConn);
sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd2.Parameters["@n"].Value = currentpage;
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@psize", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd2.Parameters["@psize"].Value = pageSize;
sqlCmd2.Prepare();
sqlConn.Open();
sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
var reader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

в reader возвращаются данные типа `SqlDataReader`, для представлений нужны `IEnumerable`. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Создать переменную типа, который реализует интерфейс IEnumerable и записать туда необходимые данные. Например:

```
//MyClass - ваш тип данных
List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MyList.Add(new MyClass() {...});
    }
}
//Дальше передаете лист куда нужно
```